# Firebase Search Query startAt endAt

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a problem when querying for search process with Firebase Rest api. I use the startAt and endAt parameters for the first and last search, but it still doesn't list it.

[https://myprojectdemo.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy="title"&startAt="Car"&endAt="Car\uf8ff"&print=pretty](https://myprojectdemo.firebaseio.com/posts.json?orderBy=%22title%22&startAt=%22Car%22&endAt=%22Car%5Cuf8ff%22&print=pretty)

I make a GET request this way.

```
"-WE2QEYJx8gaOUkOsvWkV": {
  "title" : "Red Car",
  "category" : "Other" 
},
"-WE2KSBJx8gaOUkOsvWkV": {
  "title" : "White Car",
  "category" : "Other" 
}
```

I have an output like above.
There are two shipments titled White Car and Red Car. When I search for car, I want both of them to come out. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're trying to do is find strings the **end** with some substring.  You can only search for strings that **begin** with some substring.  Realtime Database does not support substring queries in any other way except for string prefixes.

If you want to be able to search for items that are cars, consider adding another piece of data to each child indicating that it is a car type object, and use that to filter your result set.  Using the title as you have it now will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this the same in Firestore?

Comment: Yes. you should read the documentation to understand Firestore's capabilities.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries